# matplotlib plot vs elapsed time

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

How can I plot elapsed time from first data point with format as HH:MM:SS on x axis where the hours don't roll over at 24 hours. I tried using DateFormatter with "%H%M%S but the hours rollover.

Comment: Indeed you will need to use a `FuncFormatter` to get your custom labels.

Comment: Solid that worked